# angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this warning when I run gulp in command line terminal.
I have added the angular.js file in HTML code. I can't figure out the problem.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
     content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!--build:css styles/main.css-->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--endbuild-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a aria-controls="all menu" role="tab" ng-click="menuCtrl.select(1)" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(1)}">The Menu</a></li>

                <li role="presentation">
                    <a aria-controls="appetizer" role="tab" ng-click="menuCtrl.select(2)" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(2)}">Appetizers</a></li>

                <li role="presentation">
                    <a aria-controls="mains" role="tab" ng-click="menuCtrl.select(3)" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(3)}">Mains</a></li>

                <li role="presentation">
                    <a aria-controls="desserts" role="tab" ng-click="menuCtrl.select(4)" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(4)}">Desserts</a></li>


                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active"> 
                <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes | filter:menuCtrl.filtText">
                  <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#"><img ng-src={{dish.image}} class="media-object img-thumbnail" alt="Uthappizza"></a>
                    </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}</h2>
                      <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{dish.label}}</span>
                      <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                      <p>{{dish.description}}</p>

                  </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--build:js scripts/main.js-->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <!--endbuild-->


</body>

</html>`
```

app.js file is as follows:

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp',[])

        .controller('menuController',function(){

                                       this.tab=1;
                                       this.filtText="";


                                        var dishes=
                                              [
                                               {
                                                 name:'Uthapizza',
                                               image:'images/uthapizza.png',
                                               category:'mains',
                                               label:'Hot',
                                               price:'4.99',
                                               description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                                               comment: ''

                                              },
                                              {

                                                name:'Zucchipakoda',
                                                image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                                                category: 'appetizer',
                                                label:'',
                                                price:'1.99',
                                                description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                                                comment: ''

                                              },
                                              {

                                                name:'Vadonut',
                                                image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                                                category: 'appetizer',
                                                label:'New',
                                                price:'1.99',
                                                description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                                                comment: ''

                                              },
                                              {
                                              name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                                              image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                                              category: 'dessert',
                                              label:'',
                                              price:'2.99',
                                              description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                                              comment: ''

                                              }
                                              ];
                                   this.dishes=dishes;


                                    this.select=function(settab){

                                        this.tab=settab;

                                        if(settab===2){
                                            this.filtText="appetizer";
                                        }
                                        else if(settab===3){
                                            this.filtText="mains";
                                        }
                                        else if(settab===4){
                                            this.filtText="dessert";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            this.filtText="";
                                        }
                                    };

                                    this.isSelected=function(checktab){

                                        return(this.tab===checktab);
                                    };



        });
```

`

[this is the error when I run gulp in command line prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23t6r.png)

Comment: call `angular` script at top of the other scripts

Comment: Which gulp task reported the error? Was it eslint or other static checking?

Comment: This is just a gulp warning. Your app.js file doesn't know of the variable `angular`. You can either ignore the warning, or configure gulp so it knows of angular

Comment: can you help how should I configure gulp then

Comment: @Radhika issue sorted?

Comment: not yet @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0):

Move your AngularJs file to inside HEAD tag from BODY. It will work fine.

Comment: How did you install all of those _bower_components_? By _bower install_ or you just downloaded it from websites?

Comment: I did it using bower install - all the components are there in bower folder

Answer (score 0):

Yor error shows in line no 5, but your original file shows angular reference in 
some different line.

(i) Try re running the app again.

(ii)Check the network tab in chrome,if the angular reference is loaded correctly.

if not change the path to be correct one and do the test again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried after removing 'use strict' in app.js file and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Angular needs jQuery, might want to include that aswell e.g..

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Make sure you include it before you include the Angular files